# installing Xdebug on CentOS7, I get error undefined symbol: compiler_globals

Tags: php, centos, xdebug

I define the xdebug.so path on php.ini.

but I can't see xdebug info in phpinfo() function.

and error comps up like below.

> Failed loading /usr/lib64/php/modules/xdebug.so:  /usr/lib64/php/modules/xdebug.so: undefined symbol: compiler_globals

How can I resolve this issue?

Using php 7.1.4 version.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure that Xdebug is compiled using right `php-config`.

Manually download `xdebug.tgz` from https://xdebug.org/download.php and then follow the instructions on https://xdebug.org/wizard.php.

Just make sure that:

1. When you do the `phpize` step - you use the right `phpize` binary for your PHP installation. If it is a custom installation it will usually be something like `/usr/local/php/bin/phpize`
2. Same goes for running the `./configure` step. Provide the path to correct `php-config` binary like this: `./configure --with-php-config=/usr/local/php/bin/php-config`

Only then you can complie the extension and copy the `xdebug.so` file to extension directory. Also remember to `make clean` first if u compiled that directory at least once before.

Comment: This was my solution for Ubuntu 18.0.4 with php 7.3, paths were `/usr/bin/phpize7.3` and `--with-php-config=/usr/bin/php-config7.3`